# How to find vector $x$ such that $Wx = nx$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $n \ge 2$, given an $n$ x $n$ matrix W = ($w_{ij}$), where $w_{ij}$ = 1 for all $1 \le i,j \le n$.

Part a of the exercise asks to find rank(W) and nullity (W), and I've found that rank(W) and nullity(W) = n - rank(W) = n - 1. The next part of the exercise asks to find a vector $x$ so that $Wx = nx$, am I suppose to find det(W) in order to find $x$? If not then how would one obtain $x$ without the use of det(W)?

Comment: you're supposed to inspect. Have you looked for any eigenvectors? Have you written out the matrix?

Comment: Since $w_{ij}$ = 1, I assume that matrix W will just be filled with 1s and so as $(w_{ij})$. This vector $x$ is the eigenvector that I'm supposed to find, right? So it would make sense if $x$ is in $n$ x $1$ form.

Comment: Yes, any ideas what $x$ might look like?

Comment: Can only visualising $x$ with unknown variables for now, not too sure if its right or not

Comment: maybe try some numbers, and impose the condition $Wx=nx$.

Comment: Try the $2 \times 2$ case and the $3 \times 3$ cases explicitly, using row reduction to compute the nullspaces of $W - 2I$ and $W - 3I$ respectively. You should find a one-dimensional eigenspace in each case. Hopefully, the pattern for the $n \times n$ case will leap out at you.

Comment: I'm guessing you will have to let A be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with $a_{ij} = 2$, and row reduce this matrix to compute $null(A - 2I)$? Similarly with $3 \times 3$ too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Since the matrix is filled with all $1$'s, how about $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: I got two answers, one is \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix} 
and the other is n vectors of \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n-1}\\1\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}
and the entry 1 keeps on moving down e.g. $(\frac{1}{n-1},0,1,0,...,0), (\frac{1}{n-1},0,0,1,0,...,0)$

Comment: I don't see it.  As suggested in the comments, the eigenspace appears to be $1$-dimensional.

Comment: Although I'm not sure what I did wrong but, does the vector \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix} has anything to do with column space of W?

Comment: Not really.  It's just that $W\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}n\\n\\\vdots\\n\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Okay! I can see more clearly now, thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Sure. You got it.